# How can you log in a tenant's user without knowing their tenantId?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm building a multi-tenant Firebase application using Flutter. I know, Firebase [recommends against this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#multi-tenancy), but it is [supported through Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication?hl=en_US).

I've set up GCIP and I can log in global users that don't belong to a tenant. I can also log in users that belong to a tenant, *as long as I know their tenantId ahead of time*.

```
FirebaseAuth auth1 = FirebaseAuth.instance;
auth1.tenantId = "tenant1";
auth1.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "user@tenant1.com", password: "password");
print('${auth1.currentUser?.tenantId}'); // prints "tenant1"
```

The [approach described in the Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-ui) has the user select their organization/tenant from a dropdown list, but I think this approach is a bad user experience and would quickly become unwieldy once you have more than a few tenants.

Ideally, a user should be able to log in and be directed to the right tenant.

Is there any way to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(PS. I can't rely on custom URLs since this is a mobile app)

Comment: I wonder about the same...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the app can also identify the tenant based on the email ID domain. So you don't need the user to select the tenant. You can have an email id domain to tenant id mapping and use that for authentication.
Some web apps identify the tenant based on the web app subdomain the user is trying to log in to if they have a different subdomain for a different tenant.
I hope this helps.